# Windows servier-side post-receive git hook hangs

Tags: git, apache, githooks

I have setup Git on an Apache Server and everything is working great. Now I want to setup a post-receive hook to kick off a Jenkins build.

I have written the script and tested it on the server and there is no problem. However, when I do a `git push`, it gets to the "Total" line and stops:

```
C:\develop\.ws\git-repo>git push
Username for 'https://internal.git.repo.com': user
Password for 'https://user@internal.git.repo.com':
Enumerating objects: 5, done.
Counting objects: 100% (5/5), done.
Delta compression using up to 12 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 289 bytes | 289.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
```

Looking on the server, I can see the that the script has attempted to start, but it is hung and using one core's worth of CPU:

[image]

As the script seemed to be causing a problem, I simply tried the sample script by renaming it removing the "sample" extension, but that exhibits the same behaviour. So i change the script to:

```
#!/bin/sh
exit 0
```

or

```
#!C:/git-2.25.1/bin/sh.exe
exit 0
```

But still the same.

What's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved. Speaking to a IT guy over the weekend, the suggestion was that the user used to run the Apache Server maybe the cause. Presently the service was run using "Local System Account". Once changed to an actual user, the sh.exe no longer hangs.